# Replace letter in ebook

Tags: regex

I am sight impaired.  I use the Voice Dream app for iOS. It is a text to speech app.  For some reason there is a mistake in many of the books from BookShare when the book is compiled for the app in that whenever there should be a question mark, there is a capital "T".  This is annoying to listen to when the book is read.  One feature of the app is that it allows you to change the pronunciation of words phonetically and with RegEx.

The question is, I would like to find every instance in the ebook where there is a capital "T" at the end of a word and replace it with a question mark. Will you help with this?

An example would be the question above it would be in the ebook, "Will you help with thisT" instead of with a question mark.

Comment: try this `T{1,}\b` and replace it with single `?`..sometimes there can be more than one question mark

Comment: Try adding this rule: `"T\b",2,N,"?",0` (or `"T\\b",2,N,"?",0`). This for the pronunciation dictionary text mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (probably not the right language for your app, but it demonstrates the regex) :

```js
str = 'Will you help with thisT Will you help with thisT'

var output = str.replace(/(T)\b/g, '?');

$('#input').html(str);
$('#output').html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```